# Excel VBA: Is it possible to get to the "New-School" print preview via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I couldn't find a good answer other than one site referring to Excel's print preview as "New-School" and "Old-School."

Essentially, my question is: Is there a way to call up the "New-School" print preview via code?

I am currently using this: `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show` and it works fine for what I need, but it takes me to a different...(Old-School?) print preview.  I've tried recording a macro when going File>Print but that just ends up being a direct feed to the printer.

Here's my examples:

New-School:[image]

Old-School:[image]

Thank you for any help!  I'm really in debt to this website!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (for getting native print preview):

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrintPreview).Show
```

or,

```
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintPreview
```

**APPENDED** (source link : [Mr.Excel1](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/79535-printing-visual-basic-applications-code-select-printer.html) and [Mr.Excel2](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/577026-visual-basic-applications-printpreview-print-excel-2010-a.html)) :

Try this:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")
```

or

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
```

or

```
SendKeys "%FP%", True
'= same as pressing in turn the keys Alt, F, P, Alt (to turn back off the little letter labels that appear after the first press of Alt)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a go as soon as the little one will let me!

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it.  Both of those lines took me to the "Old-School" print preview I showed above.  Other than using SendKeys, I haven't really found a way.  Thank you though.

Comment: See appended answer. Tell which one works for you. Then I can edit the answer if necessary.

Comment: Sorry this took awhile to respond, but I did test each of these.  The first one: `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")` does exactly what I requested.  The other two take me to print related dialogs, but nothing that I'm familiar with.

The challenge for me now, is to figure out how to delay the Yes/No dialog that is now popping up in the "New-School" print preview that you helped me with...when it is supposed to fire after the print job is sent to the printer.  But, I'll figure that one out...I know I've seen that question answered around here.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

### FAST ANSWER:

**Yes**, just use this code line in your Macro:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")
```

### Extra:

You can specify WHICH sheets are going to be printed, using this line just before:

```
Sheets(Array("Name of Sheet 1", "Name of Sheet 2")).Select
```